# TM symbol in JSP email content - IBM WCS

Tags: jsp, servlets, encoding, websphere-commerce

When I try to trigger an email content as JSP the TM symbol is diplayed as ?. No issues with the other symbols like Copyright or Registered mark. I tried

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

and

```
<% response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" ); %>
```

nothing works. When I try with contenttype - UTF-8 all symbols breaks but when I try with ISO-8859-1 all other symbols displays perfect except TM.
Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because ISO-8859-1 doesn't understand the TM symbol for some reason. So I changed the encoding type to `<% response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=windows-1252" ); %>`